# How can I use Teamviewer anonymously with TOR network?

Tags: ip, sniffing, tor, teamviewer, privacy

I would like to be able to use Teamviewer *anonymously* to avoid revealing my real IP address while I access sensitive data on my remote server. The data being transferred is encrypted.

I have looked into TOR (and AdvOR), but am unable to get TeamViewer to work with either. I have set Teamviewer proxy to 127.0.0.1:9050 (default TOR client port) but using Wireshark I am still able to see my real IP address. Both client and server are running Windows. What am I doing wrong?

Is it because TOR's SOCKS protocol is unable to handle Teamviewer's UDP traffic? If TOR isn't the right way to go about it, please let me know what is.

Comment: why not just use a VPN tunnel ? tor's bandwidth throughput is horrific, and i dont think it deals with udp, either.

Comment: tor doesnt use any real security measures it anonymizes you ip by connecting through thr tor grid but thats really all it does and as sirex said its abysmally slow

Answer (score 5):

The proxy settings only apply to your connection to TeamViewer's servers used for UDP hole-punching; the UDP connection is always direct.

[RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) and VNC, on the other hand, use only TCP, so you can connect using them over Tor.