# Preventing true IP Visibility when allowing Teamviewer control

Tags: vpn, ip, teamviewer

Is it possible to prevent IP from a client(me) being controlled from a third party via teamviewer(or alike).

When using VPN with teamviewer, is the ip still visible to the controller if they were using wireshark or alike?

I wish to be able to allow a user to control my computer with teamviewer, without revealing the true IP.

Any reference or alike would be much appreciated as endless searches have returned nothing of use.

Comment: Just uninstall Teamviewer and/or don't allow that third-party access to your computer.

Comment: [Here is a relevant question](http://superuser.com/questions/339653/how-can-i-use-teamviewer-anonymously-with-tor-network?rq=1)